# Remove entries of a dictionary that are not in a set

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given the following dictionary and set:

```
d = {1 : a, 2 : b, 3 : c, 4 : d, 5 : e }
s = set([1, 4])
```

I was wondering if it is possible to remove all dictionary entries that are not contained in the set (i.e. 2,3,5).
I am aware that i can achieve this by iterating over the dictionary and check each key but since i'm new to Python and came across many "shortcuts" so far I was wondering if there exists one for this particular problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
d = {1 : 'a', 2 : 'b', 3 : 'c', 4 : 'd', 5 : 'e' }
s = set([1, 4])
```

Since you should not modify a dictionary while itering over it, you have two possibilities to create a new dictionary.

One is to create a new dictionary from the old one filtering values out:

```
d2 = dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k in s)
```

The second one is to extract the keys, intersect them with the `s`-set and use them to build a new dictionary:

```
d2 = dict((k, d[k]) for k in set(d) & s)
```

The third one is to remove the elements directly from `d`:

```
for k in set(d) - s:
    del d[k]
```

Comment: phew, Python is confusing. Why is it not good to modify a dictionary while iterating over it?

Comment: It is not good to modify any container while iterating over it, in any language. This is because the iterator can get confused. In general, the iterator is expecting the container's internal state to stay as it is right now, in order to be able to figure out where the "next" element is. For example, when you iterate over a sequence, the iterator may be based on an index... if you remove the element that's going to come next anyway, and then the index is blindly incremented, you effectively skip an element, and may end up out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two nice solutions:

```
d = {1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e" }
keep_keys = set((1, 4))

# option 1, builds a new dictionary
d2 = {key:d[key] for key in set(d) & keep_keys}

# option 2, modifies the original dictionary
map(d.__delitem__, frozenset(d) - keep_keys)
```

If speed is what you want you should profile which one of the two are faster.

Comment: Will raise `KeyError` if something is in `remove` and not in `d`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
d = {1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c", 4 : "d", 5 : "e" }
s = set([1, 4])
r = { k:d[k] for k in ( d.viewkeys() - s ) }
```