# Delete all dict items except for some specific ones

Tags: python

### Delete all dict items except for some

**Problem**
I have given some dict with an arbitrary number of items (for simplicity with two items):

```
dictionary = {'foo': baz, 'bar': baz}
```

I want to delete/remove all items, which are not within a defined list of keys.

```
keys_to_keep = ['foo']
```

Expected result:

```
dictionary = {'foo': baz}
```

However I want to do this without creating a new dict, so I want to modify the original dict.

**My Attempts**
Simple for loop.

```
for key in dictionary.keys():
    if key not in keys_to_keep:
        del dictionary[key]
```

**Question**
The above mentioned implementation works, but I was wondering if there is a shorter/faster solution to this problem. Maybe something like the example below, but (as I said) without creating a new dict.

```
dictionary = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if key in keys_to_keep}
```

Thanks.

*References*
[Related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387575/delete-all-keys-except-one-in-dictionary)

Comment: What's the reason for the constraint of not building a new dict?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove entries of a dictionary that are not in a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735504/remove-entries-of-a-dictionary-that-are-not-in-a-set). This removes the `if` check which I believe is as short as you can get (in-place...)

Comment: Acually the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735595/6045800) does it in one line...

Comment: @blhsing I had some issues with the creation of a new dict within the recursion I'm using it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for this reference, but shouldn't you avoid calling "__delitem __"?

Comment: I don't see a special reason not to... It's basically the functino form of `del` to be able to use inside a `map`